# Pygame screen shows black, using Mac

Tags: python, pygame

I know there are several questions already about this topic, but unfortunately I haven't found the answer(s) working for me...

I'm trying to do a tic tac toe and even it is running, the screen shows black or black with broken green lines...

I already tried a different pygame version, didn't help.
At the moment I am using: Pygame 2.0.3 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.3)

My code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 300
screen_height = 300

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('tic tac toe')

def draw_grid():
    bg = (255, 0, 0)
    grid = (50, 50, 50)
    screen.fill(bg)
    for x in range(1, 3):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, grid, (0, x * 100), (screen_width, x * 100))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, grid, (x * 100, 0), (x * 100, screen_height))

run = True
while run:

    #add event handlers
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `draw_grid` is never called. However when I call `draw_grid` then the program works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You never call draw_grid that fills you screen

Try:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 300
screen_height = 300

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('tic tac toe')

def draw_grid():
    bg = (255, 0, 0)
    grid = (50, 50, 50)
    screen.fill(bg)
    for x in range(1, 3):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, grid, (0, x * 100), (screen_width, x * 100))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, grid, (x * 100, 0), (x * 100, screen_height))

run = True
while run:

    #add event handlers
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    draw_grid()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

The black screen isn't a problem with your pygame version. You aren't actually calling the function anywhere. This means that the `draw_grid()` function isn't executing it's code.

To fix this, either type `draw_grid()` above the `while run:` loop to execute it once before the game starts.
Alternatively, you can type `draw_grid()` in the `while run:` loop to draw the tic tac toe screen every frame.

*The `draw_grid()` command is what executes the code in the `draw_grid()` function.*

[More info on functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.